# Inheritance of length based css properties in rem unit from root html element

Tags: html, css, width, units-of-measurement

I know that the rem css unit is a relative unit which is used to derive font sizes from the root element i.e html.

My question is- how are length based css properties like width, height, padding, margin, if specified in rem - for any element derived from the html element.

As an example:

```
<html class="basicStyle">
<body> 
<div id="view">This is some content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style:

```
.basicStyle{width:500px; font-size:20px}
#view{width:3rem; font-size:2rem}
```

If I try this out in chrome, the width of the #view div should be 3*500px = 1500px - However it is not so.

I want to know if we specify the width or padding of an element in rem - from which element and how is it calculated - to get the computed width.

Any documentation is welcome too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rem` unit is equal to the value of the `font-size` on the root element:

> **rem unit**
>   Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element. When specified on the font-size property of the root element, the rem units refer to the property’s initial value.

*Font-relative lengths: the em, ex, ch, rem units (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths)*

In this case the `rem` unit will be equal to `20px` as this is the `font-size` set in `.basicStyle`.

If you use `rem` to compute the `width` of an element it will not be based on the `width` of the root element but the `font-size`. In your example `#view` will therefore have a resultant `width` of 3 * 20 = `60px`.

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}
#view {
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="view">This is some content. If you inspect it the width will be 60px.</div>
```

Comment: thanks. very helpful. So does the font-size if the root html element changes when I resize my viewport or use a different device??